# JQL Query in Jira, maxDate and MinDate

Tags: sql, jira, jql

Using Jira Issue Search, I have two custom date fields in my project. 
I want a filter that returns the issue with the earliest date from field 1. 
I want another filter to return issue with latest date from field 2.

Has anybody done a query similar before. I dont know the correct syntax and checking on Atlassian documents doesnt mention anything about max or min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own JQL functions using a free plugin such as [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner).

To get the data from Jira database, find the id of your custom field using

```
select * from customfield
```

Then use something like this

```
select 
    pkey
    , summary
    , datevalue

from 
    customfieldvalue c
    , jiraissue i

where 
    i.id=c.issue
    and c.customfield = 10071 
    and c.datevalue in (select min(datevalue) from customfieldvalue where customfield = 10071)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the query and sort by the date field. First row is the max or min